# Rotate a Geometry Generator expression with a 180 degrees rotation

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, rotate, translate

From a point geometry layer to which apply a Geometry Generator expression to creates a new geometry, my goal is to translate this expression rotating 180 degrees, and taking as reference the opposite side of a rectangle polygon layer.

Comment: `translate(rotate($geometry, 180), [something with the centroid and x(@map_extent_center)]))`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea. I have tried to apply it, but without success. I edit my question so that you can see the problem in more detail

Comment: `translate` takes 3 parameters, a `geometry`, a `dx` and a `dy` (delta x, delta y). In your failed solution, you are passing `make_line` as `dx`.

Comment: `rotate($geometry, 180, center:=make_point(0,0))`? I don't understand what you mean as "reference" for the 0, 0 coordinate on your left side and what you mean by "the limits of a rectangle polygon".

Comment: Sorry. I don't think I explained it well. I have deleted this part of my question. What I mean is that the objective is to make a 180 degree rotation of a Geometry Generator expression and translate the expression to the opposite side of the rectangle polygon.

Comment: What rectangle polygon though? Is it a fixed thing with fixed coordinates? Do you want the expression to look at its geometry? What is its relationship to the geometry you want to use the expression on?

Comment: I answer your questions:

The rectangular polygon is a layer with fixed coordinates with the extend -3.165,-9.939 : 36.678,10.0965.

I think it is necessary for the point layer to look at the geometry of the polygon layer. After rotating, the point layer should be moved to the exact opposite side of the polygon.

The relationship of the point layer to the polygon layer is that for each point the distance to the 0.0,0.0 coordinate is calculated.  The opposite coordinate is 33.00, 0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking to rotate generic geometries, and not just points, then the `rotate` function should work. You just need to specify the right centre point - which is the centroid of the rectangle. It assumes you have a polygon layer called `Rectangle` with a single rectangle feature.

```
rotate(@geometry, 180, centroid(aggregate('Rectangle', 'array_agg', @geometry)[0]))
```

[image]

You should be able to replace the first `@geometry` with any arbitrary expression that creates a geometry - for example, `make_line(make_point(0.0,0.0),$geometry)`.

I haven't done this as I don't have the same data set as you, but there's no reason that it shouldn't work.

Comment: Perfect. Solved.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just to rotate your point within a polygon layer that has a single rectangle, you can use something like the following:

```
with_variable('centroid',centroid(aggregate('Rectangle','array_agg',@geometry)[0]),
with_variable('distance',distance(@geometry,@centroid),
with_variable('azimuth',azimuth(@geometry,@centroid),
project(@centroid,@distance,@azimuth))))
```

It relies on the fact that a rotation within a rectangle is just projecting the point from the centroid, the same distance and same angle again.

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution, and it does the expected job, and it's almost what I'm looking for. However, I add in my question some remarks. In short, I would like your solution works with any expression no matter how complex it is

Comment: @IngridIngravida, you should be able to replace `@geometry` in the `distance` and `azimuth` functions (lines 2 and 3) with any expression that creates a geometry.

Comment: @Matt, thanks a lot for this instruction. I have tried to implement it but when I get to the azimuth function there seems to be an incompatibility. I have documented this test in my question